# How to implement 2D list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a matrix having `r` rows and `c` columns. I have store the matrix in 2-D array. See figure below.

[image]

I find minimum number in each row. if the minimum number lies in first Column I add the minimum to listC1.

Consider the above figure.

In first row R1 minimum number is `2` and it lies in Column C1 I want to add the 2 in `listC1`.
In Second row R2 minimum number is `4` and it lies in Column C3 I want to add the 4 in `listC3`. In third row R3 minimum number is `5` and it lies in Column C2 I want to add the 5 in `listC2`. In nutshell if the minimum number lies in first column I will add the minimum number in first list `listC1`, if the minimum number lies in second column I will add the minimum number in second list `listC2`, if the minimum number lies in third column I will add the minimum number in third list `listC3` and so on and so forth.

Now issue that I am facing is how to create a list of list to implement the above logic. I have developed some code (see below) but its not working properly. Please help me in this regard

```
Note:  Ther number of columns may vary from 3 to 30



final float[][] matrix = {
            {2f, 8f, 5f},
            {9f, 7f, 4f},
            {8f, 5f, 6f},
            {7f, 3f, 9f},
            {1f, 5f, 5f},
            {8f, 7f, 5f},
        };

        Map<Integer, ArrayList<Float>> minsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();



        for(int row=0; row < matrix.length; row++)
        {
            float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
            int mc = 0;

            for(int col=0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)
            {
                if(matrix[row][col] < min) 
                {
                    min = matrix[row][col];
                    mc = col;
                }

                ArrayList<Float> minList = minsMap.get(mc);

                if(minList == null) 
                {
                    minList = new ArrayList<>();
                    minsMap.put(mc, minList);
                }
                minList.add(min);
            }

        }

        for(java.util.Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Float>> e : minsMap.entrySet()) 
        {
            System.out.println("Min values in column " + e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working properly"? What is it doing/not doing specifically?

Comment: You could first initialise and add all the empty nested groups then use something like `group.get(atIndex).add(minValue);`

Comment: You could check out Guava's [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)

Comment: @user1703737 the code for getting the list from the map and adding the a min value to it needs to be outside of the loop `for(int row=0; row < matrix.length; row++)`, i.e. move the closing brace of that loop above `ArrayList<Float> minList = minsMap.get(mc);` then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nestedGroup` is initialized only once an is used for all columns. This is not correct, you need a nested group for each column.

Take a look at this code, it uses a `Map` for holding the lists of minimum values.

```
private final static float[][] matrix = {
    {2f, 8f, 5f},
    {9f, 7f, 4f},
    {8f, 5f, 6f},
    {7f, 3f, 9f},
    {1f, 5f, 5f},
    {8f, 7f, 5f},
};


@Test
public void minOfMatrixColumn() {
    Map<Integer, List<Float>> minsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
        float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        int mc = 0;
        for(int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
            if(matrix[r][c] < min) {
                min = matrix[r][c];
                mc = c;
            }
        }
        List<Float> minList = minsMap.get(mc);
        if(minList == null) {
            minList = new ArrayList<>();
            minsMap.put(mc, minList);
        }
        minList.add(min);
    }
    for(Entry<Integer, List<Float>> e : minsMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Min values in column " + e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Min values in column 0: [2.0, 1.0]
Min values in column 2: [4.0, 5.0]
Min values in column 1: [5.0, 3.0]
```

Note that the lists are not ordered by column index.

Comment: Min values in column 0: [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 8.0]

Comment: Min values in column 1: [7.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 7.0]

Comment: Min values in column 2: [4.0, 5.0]

Comment: @user1703737 for witch inputs did you get the results above? can you post your input and the expected results in your question as an edit?

Comment: Dear! my input is 2D matrix array that you have mentioned in your answer

Comment: @user1703737 did you use the exact same code in my answer or did you edit your own code? In le later case please update you question with edited code, otherwise i dont see why/how you have got a different output from what i posted. For example the ouput `column 0: [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 8.0]` implies that you have `10` rows witch the input in your question and witch i used in my answer deffinitly not have. It has only `6` rows.

Comment: Please check my code that I am using, I have edit my question